# PHP for loop update database images

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using a for loop to validate a page in PHP then using `move_uploaded_file` to move the uploaded file + also add the image path to the database. Below is my code.

```
if(empty($_FILES) === false) {
for($i=1; $i<=$items; $i++) {
     $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

  if (empty($_FILES['photo{$i}']['name']) === true) {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Please choose a file.</div>';
  } else {
      if (in_array(strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['photo{$i}']['name']))), $allowed) === false) {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">[Photo '.$i.'] Format <strong>NOT</strong> acceptable. ';
      echo 'Accepted formats: '. implode(', ', $allowed).'</div>';
      } elseif($_FILES["photo{$i}"]['size'] > 1048576) {
      echo '<div class="alert-danger">[Photo '.$i.'] Image is too big. Maximium file size is 1MB.</div>';
      } else {
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE temp SET photo{$i} = '".rand(0,999).".".in_array(strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['photo{$i}']['name']))))."' WHERE session = $session");
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo{$i}"]['tmp_name'], 'img/temp/'.rand(0,999) . '.' . in_array(strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['photo{$i}']['name'])))));
      }
  }
  }
}
```

The image doesn't move to the desired uploaded location and also does not update the file path in the database. Please can someone help?

Comment: Have you checked your error log for any messages? What have you done to debug your code?

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** using string interpolation to accomplish this.

Comment: Just from a cursory look at your code, one problem I see is that `$_FILES['photo{$i}']` should be `$_FILES["photo$i"]` as single quoted strings won't expand variables and escape sequences (except for \').  Also, your use of complex(curly) syntax in double quoted strings is unnecessary (i.e. `"photo{$i}"`) unless you have a more complex variable that you were trying to display in double quotes (like an element of an array) though this won't cause unexpected results if you include the curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everywhere that you have `'photo{$i}'` is incorrect. As elitechief21 explained in a comment above, PHP does not parse variables in single quotes., so it is literally looking for the key `photo{$i}` in `$_FILES`, treating `{$i}` as literal text.  Of course, that doesn't exist, so the script doesn't work as expected.

You need to use double quotes wherever `photo{$i}` is currently inside single quotes.